# Second asynchronous NSURLConnection doesn't call delegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

From my ApplicationDelegate, I'm doing an NSURLConnection fetch over the network (it's wrapped in a class, as you'll see below). This one seems to work correctly: I get all the data in didReceiveData and I get the completion call connectionDidFinishLoading. At the end of connectionDidFinishLoading, I instantiate one or more of a slightly different kind of wrapper class, but they're essentially the same thing. The problem is that the second NSURLConnection's delegate is never having it's methods called.

I've looked at [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319943/nsurlconnection-doesnt-call-delegate-methods) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421054/nsurlconnection-delegate-methods-not-executing) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702294/nsurlconnection-hanging-on-second-call), but all to no avail. I'm not spawning any new threads and all the [NSThread isMainThread] checks I've littered throughout the code return true.

I'm stumped. Can anyone help me out? Here's the relevant code:

App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ConnectionWrapper* w = [[ConnectionWrapper alloc] initWithParams:self
    url:[NSURL URLWithString:<url>]];
[w beginFetch];

    return YES;
}

...

-(void)fetchCompleted:(NSURL*)url directory:(NSString*)directory
{
NSLog(@"fetch completed");
}

-(void)fetchFailed:(NSURL*)url
{
NSLog(@"fetch failed");
}

...
```

ConnectionWrapper:

```
-(id)initWithParams:(id<ConnectionWrapperDelegate>)d url:(NSURL*)url
{
    delegate = d;

    connURL = url;

    return [self init];
}

-(void)beginFetch
{
    NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:connURL];
    NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [conn release];
    [request release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"append");
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection*) connection
{
    ... parsing ....

    DifferentConnectionWrapper* w = [[DifferentConnectionWrapper alloc] initWithParams:self
        url:[NSURL URLWithString:<different url>]];
    [w beginFetch];
}

-(void)fetchCompleted:(NSURL*)URL
{
    NSLog(@"completed: %@", URL);
}

-(void)fetchFailed:(NSURL*)URL
{
    NSLog(@"failed");
}
```

DifferentConnectionWrapper:

-(id)initWithParams:(id)d url:(NSURL*)url
    {
        delegate = d;

```
    connURL = url;

    return [self init];
}

-(void)beginFetch
{
    NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:connURL];
    NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [conn release];
    [request release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"append");
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection*) connection
{
    ... parsing ....

    DifferentConnectionWrapper* w = [[DifferentConnectionWrapper alloc] initWithParams:self
        url:[NSURL URLWithString:<different url>]];
    [w beginFetch];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"got response");
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"got data");
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection*) connection
{
    NSLog(@"image saver completed: %@", connURL);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error");
}
```

ConnectionWrapper and DifferentConnectionWrapper have similar functions, but there's other logic that I've omitted here for brevity.

thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It turns out that this bug was caused by something I missed. I was going into a hard spin right after that second request, which would probably screw up just about anything. Once I fixed that problem, everything worked just fine.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you’re releasing the URL connection in `-beginFetch`:

```
-(void)beginFetch
{
    NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:connURL];
    NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [conn release];
    [request release];
}
```

The URL connection object should be kept alive and released when the connection has finished loading:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection*) connection
{
    ... parsing ....

    // *** Release the connection and whatever data you’ve kept related to
    // this particular connection
    [connection release];
    [responseData release];
    // *** or [responseData setLenght:0]; depending on how you’re
    // managing responseData

    DifferentConnectionWrapper* w = [[DifferentConnectionWrapper alloc] initWithParams:self
        url:[NSURL URLWithString:<different url>]];
    [w beginFetch];
}
```

or when there’s been an error:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // *** Release the connection and whatever data you’ve kept related to
    // this particular connection
    [connection release];
    [responseData release];
    // *** or [responseData setLenght:0]; depending on how you’re
    // managing responseData

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
```

---

**Edit:** Your initialiser is a tad weird:

```
-(id)initWithParams:(id<ConnectionWrapperDelegate>)d url:(NSURL*)url
{
    delegate = d;    
    connURL = url;
    return [self init];
}
```

There’s no way to know what happens unless we see the code for `-init` and, at any rate, this should be the designated initialiser, so it shouldn’t be sending `-init` to `self` anyway. Furthermore, you should be retaining the `url` object that’s being passed to the initialiser.

The following makes more sense:

```
-(id)initWithParams:(id<ConnectionWrapperDelegate>)d url:(NSURL*)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        delegate = d;    
        connURL = [url retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Don’t forget to release the `url` object in `-dealloc` or when you’re assigning another value to `connURL`.

Comment: nothing wrong with not keeping a reference to the NSURLConnection. It will be retained by the runloop.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt Is this documented?

Comment: Can't find it right now. I'm using NSURLConnections in this way for quite a long time, so I hope I'm not wrong. But I can't find it documented.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt Hmm, I’ve checked the documentation for run loop input sources and I haven’t been able to find any mention of run loops retaining their sources unless they’re timers. If you happen to find anything about this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things: I don't see a didFailWithError: in your first wrapper class, and (a little off topic) are you leaking memory with your DifferentConnectionWrapper *w ?

Anyway,  what I would try is: see if you can invoke DifferentConnectionWrapper directly from the appDelegate instead of the ConnectionWrapper. 
 And I would try to decouple the two calls in any event.  When the first one finishes, and calls appDelegate, can't you launch your DifferentConnectionWrapper from there?

I realize this doesn't explain your problem, but you might get it working (and which of THOSE two things is more important, is an entirely different debate.)

Comment: It does look like he’s leaking his connection wrappers.

Comment: DifferentConnectionWrapper works fine on its own from the App Delegate, but once I chain two connection requests, the second one goes nowhere. I know about the leak: it's just something I did for debug (I wanted to eliminate any retain/release issues).